# What sign for decimal separator uses PHP by default and can it be configured?

Tags: php, point, decimal-point

I am using `number_format` to display decimal numbers in different formats (prices, according to regional config, etc.). I prefer it to `money_format`. In any case, the number_format is used to display a text quantity, so, for example, I will display `$1,203.56` for US and `1.090,00€` for Europe. Of course, the internal calculation of sum of prices of items, etc., I use `number_format` to round prices, discounts, etc. And I use

```
number_format($price * quantity- $discounts ... , 2, ".", "");
```

I understand that this is correct and will add all values perfectly, and limited to 2 decimal points in the final result. I store this in the database, and later, in navigator screen, shows the `number_format` version for each case (text). But I am worried that in my server, they could change configuration and suddenly PHP would use `,` as decimal separator, mixing the calculated quantities? Is that possible or it is warranty that always the scientific notation of `.` as decimal points and no thousand separator will be used in calculation of numbers? I am worried because PHP is not typed, so the "type" of `number_format` is string. Must I also cast to `(float)`? The tests I have done are OK but I am worried that something may gone wrong.

Comment: Don't use `number_format` to round numbers. `number_format` is to __format__ numbers for a text-representation, not for further calculations.

Comment: store numbers as number in database, only when you display those numbers, use number_format

Comment: The problem is that I must round partial quantities to 2 decimal points, to the nearest digit, exactly as number_format does. For example, if I get a price of 25.69 and I apply a discount of 21%, I get 5.3949. I need to store and apply a discount of 5.39 exactly and I need to discard the third and subsequent decimal points. This in mandatory. Can I use other PHP function as round, floor, ceil, etc?

Comment: Yes, of course you can use the regular functions such as `round()`, `floor()` and `ceil()`, is there anything in your code that makes you think you can't?

Comment: No, I was trickied to think that the rounding behaviour of round() was not what I desired, but number_format did, so I came along with number_format using the parameters: floating number, ".", "", and everything was right in the calculations. But later though that because the return value is a string, it is not secure and there may changes in configuration which could be dangerous. Of course, as PHP is loosely typed, it doesn't matter about the type of the returned value. I now have changed those instances with `round` and everything works exactly the same, but I am much more confident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right to be worried, which is why you should store numbers in storage in their raw, *numeric* format, and not as a formatted string. Calculations should be performed on numeric values, and not values gained from reverse-engineering string representations.

So, store the number in a `DECIMAL` (or, even better, store the value in cents in an `INT` column), and then format the number in your view.

```
<?php echo '$'.number_format($price); ?>
```

Comment: Good suggestions about storing the integer format of the decimal point, as there are no divisions, everything is going to have a limited number of decimals, so in one field I can store the integer and in the other field the place of the decimal point.